# Angular 2+ forms pass validation when invalid values are freshly loaded

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a series of forms that automatically saves themselves every five minutes. The forms can, and should save *invalid* values in this process (maxLength issues are accounted for to save issues on the backend).

Also, the user can submit the form whenever they want, but to do so, the form needs to be valid.

I have all this in place so far.

The problem is, when the forms are revisited since an auto-save, without a valid user-submit occurring since, Angular loads the *invalid* values, as it should, but then indicates that the form is valid, even when some of the loaded values should not pass their validators.

I'm building some pretty advanced forms currently, but *very* new to Angular form validation. So sorry for the noob question, but how should I go about telling Angular in this case to run validation on the invalid, freshly loaded fields?

I've started cracking into dirty/pristine, touched/untouched, pending, etc., and getting a handle on it, but not sure if these are what I need or how to implement something that will mark the whole form to what I need without side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on track with the dirty/pristine/touched stuff. However, the `FormGroup` provides a method for checking this:

```
afterFormGetsPopulated() {
  this.formGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

I think that should work, but I'm not able to live test it right now. If that doesn't, each `FormControl` has the same method on it:

```
afterFormGetsPopulated() {
  this.formGroup.controls.forEach(c => c.updateValueAndValidity());
}
```

Comment: This works, however only if it is run asynchronously after the fields are populated (via setTimeout). And it needs to be run on each and every control. Fortunately, I have a function that iterates through nested forms with a passed in function.

Comment: Sounds good. Note also that by default, that method will also update all ancestors of the control it's run on. Could help clean things up a bit.